# Unpack tuples in python and the ValueError

Tags: python, tuples

If I have a tuple as follows:

```
t = ([1, 2, 3], 34, [3, 4, 5, 6], 5643)
```

when I use `enumerate` to unpack it, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

The code is:

```
for i, data in enumerate(t):
    a, b, c, d = data
```

Comment: The elements of the sequence produced by `enumerate()` always have a length of two - the index, followed by a value from the input sequence.  So your code doesn't make any sense as written.  If what you expected was for `a` to be `[1,2,3]` and so forth, that would simply be written `a, b, c, d = t`, there's no loop needed.

Comment: `a,b,c,d = 34` why did you expect this would work?

Comment: `enumerate` doesn't unpack anything.
You just iterate over t. So the first value of `data` will be [1,2,3], second 34, and so on.
Hence why you are getting this error because you are trying to unpack [1,2,3] into four variables.

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Were you expecting it to work? Why? It would be best if you could provide a [mre] including expected output, for example, you could add `print(a, b, c, d)` in the loop, or something like that. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Try the for loop with `print(i, data)` instead of `a, b, c, d = data` and it should be clear what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack the tuple without `enumerate`:

```
t = ([1, 2, 3], 34, [3, 4, 5, 6], 5643)
a, b, c, d  = t
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
34
[3, 4, 5, 6]
5643
```

Note that you were getting the error because the results of `enumerate` have `data` of different lengths for different values of `i`, as shown below (while you expect `data` to always have 4 elements exactly):

```
for i, data in enumerate(t):
    print(f'{i}: {data}')
# 0: [1, 2, 3]
# 1: 34
# 2: [3, 4, 5, 6]
# 3: 5643
```

Comment: But can we unpack it with `enumerate`?

Comment: It depends on what you want the result to be, which isn't specified. As pointed out, there is no question to answer.

Comment: @SayedSabry *what do you think `enumerate` does? What is the output you are *expecting*?